# Is there a way to specify the tab to display when the Media Uploader is displayed?

Tags: media-library

I've created a new tab in the media uploader using the 'media_upload_tabs' hook. I would like to be able to set it as the active or default tab when the media uploader is displayed. This questions is not the same as [Switch to the library tab in the media uploader](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/179019/switch-to-the-library-tab-in-the-media-uploader) which takes place after an upload. I hope there is a simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will select a custom tab labeled `Your Tab Name` when launching the Media Library for the first time.

```
add_action( 'admin_footer-post-new.php', 'wpse_default_media_library_tab' );
add_action( 'admin_footer-post.php', 'wpse_default_media_library_tab' );
function wpse_default_media_library_tab() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var my_tab_has_been_activated = 0;
    (function($) {
        $(document).ready( function() {

            // http://wordpress-hackers.1065353.n5.nabble.com/JavaScript-events-on-media-popup-td42941.html
            $(document.body).on( 'click', '.insert-media', function( event ) {
                if ( 0 == my_tab_has_been_activated ) {

                    // Locates and activates media tab with label of search_text when the Media
                    // Library is initially opened.
                    var search_text = "Your Tab Name";

                    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/36054483/3059883
                    var $search_tab = $( ".media-menu-item" ).filter( function () {
                            return $( this ).text().toLowerCase().indexOf( search_text.toLowerCase() ) >= 0;
                    }).first(); // Returns the first element that matches the text. You can return the last one with .last()
                    $search_tab.trigger( 'click' );

                    my_tab_has_been_activated = 1;
                 }
            }); 

        });
    })(jQuery);
</script><?php
}
```

To customize the code for your tab, simply change the following line so that it matches the text for your tab's menu label:

```
var search_text = "Your Tab Name"; // Change the text as needed.
```

This is not the prettiest solution, but it does work for me. It would be more elegant to do this via the wp.media API, but after quite a bit of effort, I wasn't able to pull that off.

### Custom Tabs Demo

For the sake of completeness, here is some basic demo code via [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/216284/how-to-extend-media-library-wp-4-4) which shows how to create a custom media library tab. Note that this is the pre WordPress v3.5 way of doing things. [Here's an answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/82057/2807) that deals with creating media tabs using the newer JS API.

```
add_filter( 'media_upload_tabs', 'media_upload_tabs__tab_slug' );
function media_upload_tabs__tab_slug( $_default_tabs ) {
    $newtab = array ( 'tab_slug' => 'Your Tab Name' );
    $tabs = array_merge( $_default_tabs, $newtab );

    return $tabs;
}

add_action( 'media_upload_tab_slug', 'media_upload_tab_slug__content' );
function media_upload_tab_slug__content() {
    wp_iframe( 'media_upload_tab_slug_content__iframe' );
}

function media_upload_tab_slug_content__iframe() {
    ?>
    <div>tab_slug: Add your content here.</div><?php
}
```